# Использовать нужный appsettings при публикации IIS

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, публикация-приложений, blazor-client-side

При публикации сайта на сервер мне приходится вручную копировать `appsettings настройки` из файла `appsettings.Developpement` в файл `appsettings`. Как и где можно контролировать эту часть?

*приложение `Blazor Web`*

Поделюсь подробно, как я сделала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую `сервис` для `appsettings`, сейчас не смогу найти ссылку, где именно нашла это решение. Пример класса сервис

```
namespace VashProject.AppSettings
{
    public static class ApplicationServicesSettings
    {
        public const string MySettings = "MySettings";
        public static Class MyClassValue { get; set; } = new MyClassValue();
    }

    public class MyClassValue
    {
        public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Чтобы было ясней, что есть что, добавлю `appsettings`

```json
{
  "MySettings": {
    "SomeValue": "",
  }
}
```

Ну и затем в файле `Program`:

```
builder.Configuration.GetSection(ApplicationServicesSettings.MySettings).Bind(ApplicationServicesSettings.MyClassValue);
```

Ну и чтоб вызвать:

```
string someValue = ApplicationServicesSettings.MyClassValue.SomeValue;
```

Что касается самого файла, я просто создала файл с соответствующей средой названия. `Release`

Если Вы обратите внимание красный кружок рядом с файлом `appsettings` он говорит о том, что файл я не загружаю при `коммитах` (github, devAzure и т.д.), для этого я просто добавила `gitignore` при создании проекта на платформе и в конце файла добавила строчку.

```
# Remove developpement configuration files
**/appsettings.*.json
```

[а тут тоже много интересного](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c)
[и тут,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364917/overriding-appsettings-json-in-iis)

Покажите на внятном примере, как вы настройки куда пишете, чтоб после публикации находилось все и работало.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-add-startup-cs-class-in-asp-net-core-6-project/ вроде понятно, а я не понимаю ☹️ где этот стартап класс писать, зачем его писать, если удалили после 6 версии net,,, паАмАгите

Comment: поменяйте gitignore, чтобы `.Release.json` попадал в гит

Comment: Зачем ? Мне же нужно не для гит. Мне нужно для iis,чтоб когда я публикую чтоб он использовал нужный файл, надо использовать EnvironmentVariable ,но и где и как пока не разберусь.на старой работе за меня делали эту часть так и осталось темным пятном.а тем более класса стартап нету,все в программ делают,а на внятно примере пока не вижу.гит как раз таки меня устраивает без .release @4per

Comment: И кстати вы метку клиент сайд добавили, а приложение блазор просто в вопросе.тк я теперь использую и сервер и васм......а клиентсайд по моему относится в васм.а мне в целом знать бы. Так что только блазор достаточно было

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для удобства разработки существует механизм разделения конфигурационного файла на несколько частей:

- Общая - appsettings.json (можно задать все настройки приложения тут)
- Зависимая - appsettings.{name}.json (можно переопределить настройки из общей части или добавить новые)

Имя зависимой части - {name} может задаваться в переменной окружения (например в DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Development) или даже переопределяться самим приложением

Основные виды окружений:

- Development - запуск приложения в среде разработки или тестирования
- Staging - запуск приложения в среде приближенном к продуктовом (аналог закрытой беты)
- Production - запуск в продуктовой среде

Всё это условности и можно добавлять любые свои окружения, например:

- Testing - окружение для интеграционных или юнит тестов
- Local - локальное окружение (запуск на машине разработчика в режиме debug например)

И конечно всё это просто базовые настройки, которые вы можете поменять под себя. Например загружать конфигурацию из базы, etcd, zookeeper из переменных окружения, из командной строки запуска самого приложения, из xml файла или yaml

Отвечая на ваш вопрос. Не надо ничего копировать после публикации. Один раз перенесите все общие настройки из appsettings.Development.json в appsettings.json, а частные (например строка подключения к БД) оставте.

Comment: Если я буду копировать в апсеттингс все,то зачем другие создавать при публикации. Я ищу вариант, апссетинг что то (production?) И не копируя ни разу в апсеттинг простой данные, а только название иметь доступ. В комментариях выше тоже самое что в вашем ответе. Выходит большинство просто так и делает просто в апсеттинг пишет все...а когда пушите в гитхаб девазур просто с вашим апсетингсом все ,этот файл же нужен больше как маппинг,там пишешь названия а Валю уже по среде

Comment: @Dev18 я ничего не понял из того что вы написали во втором и последнем предложении

Comment: вы когда проект сохраняете в облаке (github, devAzure...) вы свой файл appsettings оставляете заполненым со всем значениями настроек? ведь по моему он нужен как некий map-карта, того какие у вас настройки есть, а сам value пустое. и заполнено в среде (appsettings.Developpement.Release итд)

Comment: @Dev18 как я и написал в ответе - конфига может строится из нескольких файлов, которые могут переопределять и добавлять новые значения в результат. Поэтому appsettings.json содержит часть общей конфигурации, а appsettings.Development.json определяет (переопределяет) специфичную для запуска в режиме разработки.
После выкладки у всех appsettings.json заполнен конкретными значениями, причём значения можно и не заполнять вовсе и это норма.

Comment: (Поэтому appsettings.json содержит часть общей конфигурации,....) *часть общей конфигурации* Николай, скажите пожалуйста на реальном примере какая часть, что именно, из личного опыта. Спасибо

Comment: @Dev18 например классическое todo приложение (список дел по нашему). В обую конфигурацию уйдут всевозможные ограничения создаваемых пользователем сущностях (например максимальное количество дел в одном списке, максимальное количество списков на одного пользователя и т.д.), а в частный конфиг пойдёт строка подключения к базе данных или для тестирования можно переопределить некоторые ограничения из основного конфига.

Comment: ок, я как раз о строке итп. Как вы ее храните, может вы вообще не в аппсеттинг кладете, а например я слышала, что вообще отдельный джейсон(не аппсеттинг) как то оформляют и не держат в проекте вообще. Но где пример увидеть, какой то внятный, и вот чтоб программист сказал, да, так делать безопасно. А вы то есть строку подключения после публикации как зовете из частного аппсеттинг ? как настраивате, что проект знает, что вот основной аппсеттинг пустой, и надо искать из аппсеттингПродакт или Релиз или что как. Спасибо

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCcxb.png у меня даже нет такого экрана у меня там совсем другое отображается...вот по этой ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor, хвалят ответ, но такое ощущение, что они показывают на примере, а как мне реализовать не понятно. Вы можете скрин экранов сделать, вот на примере строки БД. как и где храните, при публикации что делаете. спасибо

Comment: нашла, там интерфейс изменился, нажимаешь на ссылку, чтоб это модальное окно открылось https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CCjR.png а что дальше то

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuJUk.png  по-моему мне это подходит ? заменить args `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`

Comment: @Dev18 есть правило не хранить чувствительные данные (персональные данные, пароли, строки подключений т.к. они как правило содержат пароли или секреты) в репозитории, т.е. в конфигах. Их добавляют уже непосредственно в контейнер или среду в которой будет работать приложение. Самый простой вариант это переменные окружения, но  чтобы это заработало нужно правильно сконфигурировать приложение

Comment: нужно....., правило....., правильно........ а примеры где☹️теория красиво звучит, но не ясно ведь без примеров. Вы со своего примера если покажите, будет ясней может

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147742/discussion-between-nikolay-and-dev18).

Answer (score 2):

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor)

*Мне понравилось решение, оставлю здесь, переведу ответ как есть в источнике*

Для .NET 6 я нашел это лучшим решением:

```
var webAppOptions = new WebApplicationOptions()
{   
    Args = args,

    #if DEBUG
        EnvironmentName = Environments.Development,
    #else
        EnvironmentName = Environments.Production,
    #endif

};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webAppOptions);
```

Мы также можем прочитать `EnvironmentName` из файла конфигурации и установить его `WebApplicationOptions` перед вызовом `WebApplication.CreateBuilder`

Теперь мы также можем протестировать производственную среду на нашей машине разработки. Нам просто нужно переключиться на `release` сборку, и у нас есть производственная среда.

Нет необходимости устанавливать какие-либо переменные ОКРУЖАЮЩЕЙ СРЕДЫ.

Преимущество такого подхода также в том, что мы не можем случайно создать сборку релиза, работающую в `Development` среде.

пример на гитхаб https://github.com/Dev18000/ExampleAppsettings/blob/master/ExampleAppsettings/Program.cs

Comment: Крайне не рекрмендую такой подход в продуктовой разработке, т.к. мы не сможем выложить на стейдж или прод дебажную версию приложения, но это пол беды, основная прблема возникнет если мы все же выложим дебажную версию в прод.

Comment: @Nikolay а зачем на прод дебажную версию выкладывать ? когда я публикую приложение, оно публикуется в релИз ведь 

Comment: Релиз не означает прод, также прод не означает релиз )

Comment: Прод это то, что мы опубликовали, (к примеру на сервер IIS) (верно?нет-поправьте пожалуйста) Через Релиз только я могу публиковать, так как если я публикую проект, я открываю от имени администратора визуалСтудио, ставлю на Релиз проект и публикую...в данном контексте по моему они равны

Comment: Опубликовать можно и debug версию. Это всё настраивается.

Comment: @Nikolay а зачем дебаг версию публиковать. зачем? она же под своим названием несет значение. зачем она нужна в публикации, если я там не дебаглю, или мы можем дебаЖить версию которая опубликована на сервере? как ?